# enterprise message queue system for windows server

Tags: windows, message-queue

I'm looking for a message queuing system that runs on windows server similar to jms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMS is [Java Message Service](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/). It is an API and isn't platform dependant.

For implementations that can run on the Windows platform: [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html) runs on Windows, as does [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/service-guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

[TIBCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIBCO) makes a message server, [Enterprise Message Server](http://www.tibco.com/software/messaging/enterprise-message-service/default.jsp) (EMS). It is based on the JMS specification.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [AMQP](http://jira.amqp.org/confluence/display/AMQP/About+AMQP) based systems such as [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BizTalk](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hosted message queue service like [StormMQ](http://stormmq.com)...basically why host the MQ when you can use a cloud based service instead.